# how to assign a character numerical to a integer type (same char numerical should be stored)

Tags: c, string, char, printf

i am trying to store a **numerical character** into a **integer**

(string which contains ip address , need to store it in a integer )

for that i am using this way to store the char numerical

```
int a;
char ch = '1';
a = ch;
printf("%d\n",a);
printf("%d\n",a - 48);
```

**output**

```
49
1
```

instead of doing **a - 48** to store the char('1') as integer any better way is there to do that,

Comment: If you want convert IP address to an int and back use instead the functions `inet_addr` and `inet_ntoa`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use

```
int a = ch - '0'; // '0' has acsii value 48
```

It's the common way to convert a numerical char to the corresponding integer.

Answer (score 0):

Try **one** of the following options:

1. `a = ch-'0';`
2. `printf("%d\n",a-'0');`

Or alternatively, just do `printf("%c\n",ch);`.

BTW, `ch` is not a **string of numerical**, it is a **numerical character**.

Comment: any build in functions available

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert one character at a time, herohuyongtao's solution is fine. If you want to convert a string (several characters) at a time, you can use `std::atoi` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = atoi( &ch );
printf( "%d",a );
```